# Using a Batch file to automatically create a backup file with 5 running iterations

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking for general advice on if this is possible/best way to go about it.

I have a split Access database. The back-end file is called data.mdb. In the same directory as data.mdb I want to place a .bat that will automatically create a copy of data.mdb every night. However, I don't want to create infinite backups. I just want a running list of the 5 most current. That is, after the 5th night, each subsequent backup should overwrite the oldest of the 5 versions of copy - data.mdb.

Is it possible to do this with a batch file, and could you give me examples about what the code would look like?

I'm assuming I'll have to alter windows settings somehow - maybe in msconfig - to make the .bat run automatically and at a specific time. Is there a way to do this within the .bat itself. My intuition says no, but that would be ideal.

If you think  there is a better way to get the same result, I'd be interested in your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Do a modulus calculation with the day of the year of the julian day number for example. And schedule the batch to run daily.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following batch file could be used for this task:

```
@echo off
set "BackupFolder=Backup"
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "FileDate=%%I"
set "FileDate=%FileDate:~0,4%-%FileDate:~4,2%-%FileDate:~6,2%"
md "%BackupFolder%" 2>nul
copy /Y "data.mdb" "%BackupFolder%\data_%FileDate%.mdb" >nul
for /F "skip=5 delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /O-N "%BackupFolder%\data_*.mdb" 2^>nul') do del "%BackupFolder%\%%I"
```

The **WMIC** command outputs the current local date and time for example as:

```
LocalDateTime=20170410074206.062000+120
```

Just the string after the equal sign is of interest and assigned to variable `FileDate` by first **FOR** loop.

From this string just year, month and day is of interest for file name of backup file. Therefore the fourth command line uses string substitutions to get the local date in format `YYYY-MM-DD`. The string assigned finally to environment variable `FileDate` for the example is:

```
2017-04-10
```

A **COPY** is made of `data.mdb` into a backup folder always created if not already existing with an underscore and value of `FileDate` appended to file name. In your batch file the file `data.mdb` should be specified with full path and also the backup folder defined in second line should be specified with full path and not just with `Backup`. This is important later on running the batch file as scheduled task.

Then command **DIR** is executed to list all `data_*.mdb` files in backup directory in bare format because of `/B` sorted alphabetically in reverse order because of `/O-N`. The result is for example:

```
data_2017-04-10.mdb
data_2017-04-07.mdb
data_2017-04-06.mdb
data_2017-04-05.mdb
data_2017-04-04.mdb
data_2017-04-03.mdb
```

The first 5 lines which are the 5 newest files are skipped on processing this output by **FOR** loop. All other files are deleted which is usually only one file, the oldest file according to date in file name.

Configure in Windows task scheduler a scheduled task executing this batch file for example on Monday to Friday at 23:45 o'clock at night. By default the current directory on executing a batch file as scheduled task is `%SystemRoot%\System32` and not the directory of the batch file which is the reason why it is recommended to specify backup folder and file `data.mdb` with full path in batch file.

It is important that the database application using `data.mdb` is not running while the batch file is executed as otherwise the file copy most likely fails because database applications usually open database files in exclusive mode, i.e. no other application can read/write the file while opened in database application.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic OS /?`
- `wmic OS GET /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` used to suppress the error messages output by **MD** if backup folder already exists and of **DIR** if there is currently no file `data_*.mdb` in backup directory for example because of a manual deletion. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped in **FOR** command line with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal character on parsing the **FOR** command line, but as redirection operator later on execution of **DIR** command by **FOR** in a separate command process in background.